# Type erasure leads to missing parameter type for expanded function

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I have written the following class that I later want to use according to the [Pimp My Library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) pattern:

```
class ListX[A] (list: List[A]) {

    def zipMap[A, B, C] (that: List[B], op: (A, B) => C): List[C] =
        list.zip(that).map({
            case (a: A, b: B) => op(a, b)
        })
}
```

This compiles with warnings:

```
[warn] /src/main/scala/ListX.scala:8: abstract type pattern A is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]             case (a: A, b: B) => op(a, b)
[warn]                      ^
[warn] /src/main/scala/ListX.scala:8: abstract type pattern B is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]             case (a: A, b: B) => op(a, b)
[warn]                            ^
[warn] two warnings found
```

Testing it in REPL results in the following error:

```
scala> val a = new ListX(List(1, 1, 1))

scala> val b = List(1, 1, 1)

scala> val result = a.zipMap(b, _ + _)
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))

scala> val expected = List(2, 2, 2)
```

Since I am new to Scala I do not fully understand the warnings and the error. I know that there is this thing called "type erasure", but not how it works, and I can see that this probably leads to a missing type.

So what is wrong and how can I correct it?

**Update:**

Thanks to the accepted answer and its comments I managed to fix the issues and rewrote the class as follows:

```
implicit class ListX[A] (list: List[A]) {

    def zipMap[B, C] (that: List[B])(op: (A, B) => C): List[C]
    = list.zip(that).map({ op.tupled })
}
```

Comment: Type erasure won't cause compile-time errors like that. Type erasure is a problem at run-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have many issues in your code, it's not only about type erasure:

In order for scala to derive the types of your lambda, you need to put it in a separate argument group: `(that: List[B])(op: (A, B) => C)` and then call it like `zipMap(List(1, 1, 1))(_ + _)`. You can find lots of answers about this here. In short this is because scala does not know about type `B` in the group where you define it, so the first group where you've specified your type cannot infer the type

Then you have defined type parameter `A` twice. One in your class, and one in your method. You need it only once. Scala understands these two `A` as two different type parameters, so the latter `A` does not have any actual type, because it is not associated with `list: List[A]`, and scala cannot derive a type for `_ + _`.

And you need a `ClassTag` context bound for your type parameters to fight the type erasure. It is written as `[A : ClassTag]` In short this allow scala to attach type information for both of your `A` and `B` in order to use that in scala match.

So the result code is:

***(please see the code in the end of the answer as a better version, this one can be simplified)***

```
  class ListX[A : ClassTag](list: List[A]) {

    def zipMap[B: ClassTag, C](that: List[B])(op: (A, B) => C): List[C] =
      list.zip(that).map({
        case (a: A, b: B) => op(a, b)
      })
  }

  println(new ListX[Int](List(2, 2, 2)).zipMap(List(1, 1, 1))(_ + _))
```

**Update**

After thinking a bit about @Łukasz comment I realized that I made a mistake: you really don't need a `ClassTag` here. The problem why it generated the warning is that you specified that your `case` should have type `(A, B)` explicitly. Instead you can give the compiler an opportunity to figure out this by itself, and if I understand what's happening here correctly - compiler can figure out that you don't need `ClassTag`s here as they do nothing. See this:

```
  class ListX[A](list: List[A]) {

    def zipMap[B, C](that: List[B])(op: (A, B) => C): List[C] =
      list.zip(that).map({
        case (a, b) => op(a, b)
      })
  }

  println(new ListX[Int](List(2, 2, 2)).zipMap(List(1, 1, 1))(_ + _))
```

This does not produce any warnings.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! With the changes in place the warnings and the original error are gone, but at runtime I receive a `scala.MatchError` when running the `println(...)` from your example. Do you have an idea on that?

Comment: I get no errors with this code. It also seems to work without implicit `ClassTag`s

Comment: @Łukasz It works, but it gives a warning. There isn't actually much sense in `ClassTag`s here, because even though it won't check over having `A` and `B` as the types of the list - the compiler already checks that during compile time and you can never pass any other type there if you use the code legibly, but I still feel like having `ClassTag` there makes the code better and safer. I'm not sure how much different does it take. You probably can execute it via reflection in a not proper way if you do not have `ClassTag` context bound

Comment: @hielsnoppe I usually run a code before posting it here at least once - a good habit. Can you post the whole file you are running, maybe you have an issue elsewhere?

Comment: as @Archeg said, there is no need for a class tag. I also doubt that it is required in this situation to introduce a seperate argument group, but is correct to say that the extra type parameter is not required. It is also not required to pattern match against the types. Though they are indeed erased, they are known at compile time, so doing a simple `case (a,b) => ` is fine. I think this line is absolutely sufficient to solve the problem: 

`def zipMap[B, C] (that: List[B], op: (A, B) => C): List[C] = list.zip(that).map { op.tupled }`

Comment: @Łukasz I just realized how right were you, thanks. Please see update

Comment: @Markus You are right in everything except the method arg group - the `B` type is not known, so you need to either specify it or separate `op` argument in a group for a compiler to infer that. At least that's how it works for scala I have (2.11.2)

Comment: @archeg - Sorry I just realized that your answer was hidden in the "Update" all along. For the sake of clarity the answer should be edited to the final correct answer.

Comment: @Markus I prefer to leave the previous answer as the history remainder so all of these comments won't become strange and meaningless. I have added a small mention before the code that you need to look to the end of the answer. Does it suite you?

Comment: Thank you all for your interest and help! With your answer and comments in mind I have rewritten the function and now it is simpler and working. I will add it to my question.